# what is time between repeating actions

Tags: single-word-requests

what is time between repeating actions. how to call it?

For example: I touch the table once.   Then I continuously touch the table like rubbing.

What is the time difference between touching once and touching continuously?

Comment: Are you after the word "tap" https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/tap

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The word to describe the time between things happening is

> Interval

**a period between two events or times**
*We see each other at regular intervals - usually about once a month.*

**a short period between the parts of a performance or a sports event:**
*There will be two 20-minute intervals during the opera.*

**repeated after a particular period of time or a particular distance:**
*In the event of fire, the alarm will sound at 15-second intervals/at intervals of 15 seconds.*

[Source](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/interval)

Answer (score 0):

In engineering, when there is a regularly repeating pattern, the time between repeats is called the `period` of the pattern. (corrected thanks @Stuart_F)

Comment: Actually the time between each is the period. The frequency is the reciprocal of the period. https://simple.wikipedia.org/wiki/Period_(physics)